# Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Error during transaction

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

During the execution of the following piece of code, I get the message

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

And there are loads of occurrences of that in here, but I didn't find a solution to my problem.

This only happens to me because I'm running `_db.SaveChanges()` two times inside one transaction (`_db` is my database context object), and I HAVE to do so because I need the generated ID that it gives me in order to proceed with the code.

If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it. Also, if you know a way to proceed without the two `_db.SaveChanges()` or with a different way of approaching the transaction, I welcome you to show it.

```
using (var trans = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        var f = cbxFornecedor.SelectedItem as Fornecedor;
        var c = new Compra
                {
                    CompraId = compra.CompraId,
                    DataCompra = dtpDataCompra.Value,
                    ListaProdutos = new List<ListaProdutos>(),
                    Fornecedor = f,
                    Referencia = tbxReferencia.Text,
                    Situacao = rbtEntregue.Checked
                };

        _db.Compras.Add(c);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var cada in _itens)
            c.ListaProdutos.Add(new ListaProdutos
                    {
                        Compra = c,
                        CompraId = c.CompraId,
                        Produto = cada.ProdutoClasse,
                        ProdutoId = cada.ProdutoClasse.ProdutoId,
                        Valor = cada.ValorTotal,
                        Quantidade = cada.Quantidade,
                    });

        foreach (var cada in c.ListaProdutos)
            if (_db.ListaProdutos.Find(cada.CompraId, cada.ProdutoId) != null)
                _db.Entry(cada).State = EntityState.Modified;
            else
                _db.ListaProdutos.Add(cada);

        _db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();

        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, @"Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

And, just to be clear, I know that my problem is with that fact that the transaction is there. I tried removing it and it worked. Also, if I take out the second `_db.SaveChanges()`, it works too.

The exception is only thrown in the second `_db.SaveChanges()`, and only if it is surrounded by the transaction block.

Comment: Does CompraId property genereted ID for Compra? And if yes, then why do you assign it when creating `new Compra { CompraId = compra.CompraId; ` ?

Comment: Well, I will modify the code to handle update too, but right now I can guarantee that the code is always 0 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not direct answer to your question, but it may be helpful.

You do not need to specify Compra and CompraId for `new ListaProdutos` because EF smart enough to figure it out. Also it looks like that you do not need `_db.ListaProdutos.Find(cada.CompraId, cada.ProdutoId) != null` check because cada.CompraId - is new Id and it can not be in DB at this moment. Also you  do not need `_db.ListaProdutos.Add(cada);` because EF already new that you are adding this records. Can you try next code?

```
var f = cbxFornecedor.SelectedItem as Fornecedor;
var c = new Compra
    {
        DataCompra = dtpDataCompra.Value,
        ListaProdutos = new List<ListaProdutos>(),
        Fornecedor = f,
        Referencia = tbxReferencia.Text,
        Situacao = rbtEntregue.Checked
    };

_db.Compras.Add(c); 

foreach (var cada in _itens)
    c.ListaProdutos.Add(new ListaProdutos
        {
            Produto = cada.ProdutoClasse,
            ProdutoId = cada.ProdutoClasse.ProdutoId,
            Valor = cada.ValorTotal,
            Quantidade = cada.Quantidade,
        });
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Worked liked a charm man. I can actually remove the transaction block, since it only has one `_db.SaveChanges()`, but it works with it too.
As I said above, I was looking for any solution to the problem, not just the solution I was approaching, so I'm marking you as the answer. Thanks!